# Training Yolo to detect object with keypoints or landmarks

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, training-data, yolo

I have worked with yolo to detect iris region in eye in real time 
I have tied training my own dataset of iris using yolov3 darknet (library of AlexayAB ) to detect iris in real time (with webcam of smartphone for exemple ) ,
e.g:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HolVN.png

I want to mixed yolo algorithm with Landmark detection ( or Keypoints detection ) to draw points takes the form of the iris after training and detection the iris region with yolo .
I ask is it possible to do that?

Exemple The desired result :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMf7g.jpg

Comment: did you get this thing work?

Comment: I have tried other project than YOLO

Comment: Was training Yolo to search for an iris in an image successful? I can share some weights files...

Comment: Just with object detection not with landmarks